# WPF MVVM Textbox and Datagrid binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagridview

Hi I have a WPF MVVM application. I have a DatagridView and I have binded a list Items . I also have currentItem which I have set as Selected Item in Xaml

Now I have Binded another textbox to the CurrentItem.Name and I want Textbox's content to change whenever I select another item in the grid .

I have ViewModel which has INotifyProperty change implemented so don't post those as answers

Comment: Yes, but you want the UI to update when the *properties* of your data type are changed... so did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your data class also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed calling OnProperty in setter of CurrentItem Object . So the UI was never informed about this .

Answer (score 0):

i would think you can directly bind to the selected item of your datagrid, but its not tested :)

```
 <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mygrid, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```